# Materials change when I export a fbx file to Unity

Tags: materials, export, unity, file-format, .fbx

I am pretty new to Blender. I am trying to export a character from Blender to Unity, but when I import it in Unity in FBX file format, the materials get somehow mixed up, so for example the hair becomes blue, but in the blend file it is yellow.

I didn't do any complicated stuff to my material, I just set the color at the *Diffuse* section. If it matters, I initially checked the *Shadeless* box, but I unchecked it and it still doesn't work.

I also want to mention that I have all the materials applied to the character, which is only a mesh (it kinda looks like a Minecraft skin, because I chose to do it low-poly).

So should I:

- try other formats for exporting?
- unwrap the model and apply materials in Unity (I don't know how to do it)?
- give up?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, occurs because each software has a different material system.

When you export to fbx it converts the information to a "universal" compatibility format, so some types of standard information are preserved, like diffuse color, vertex paint, UV Maps, but not Blender specific settings like multi layered textures, alpha, blending mode, etc. .

Unity has a very restrictive material system that makes hard to adapt complex graphic ports. In some instances you may have even to write shaders in c# code to get good results, so for porting to Unity keep your materials with as simple setup as possible.